# How to mock a deep object?

Tags: jestjs

I have the following code inside my class method:

```
  !isUndefined(this.context.request.headers[CORRELATION_HEADER])
```

Its quite a deep object, `this.context` is passed in via the constructor, so I am able to pass in a mock here.

What is the best way to create a mock so that `headers[CORRELATION_HEADER]` is equal to `"testing"` and not undefined? `CORRELATION_HEADER` is just a constant for `"X-Correlation-Id"` but I need to provide a mock for 3 levels deep.

```
context.request.headers
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you put your test code? Do you get any error?

Comment: If the code is difficult to test then it is also difficult to use and reveals bad design. Change the code to be easy to test. It will also be easy to use and reuse (what is difficult to impossible now).